# Working with 13TH month

Tags: python, datetime

I was using the following code to format date in python 2.7:

```
month = 13 # this is right, i'm working with 13 month.
year = 2012

return datetime.strptime('{}/{}'.format(m, y), '%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%Y')
```

Now i changed to version 2.5, and the code needs changes because .format doesn't exist in this particular version. So, i'm trying like this:

```
 return (datetime.strptime(('%d/%d' % (month, year)),
                            '%m/%Y')
 )
```

Output:

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=13/2012  fmt=%m/%Y
```

Which is fine, because i'm using the month = '13', which i really need to use... is it possible to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no 13th month in a year. The code has a *number* (13); the failure to uphold the agreement for a date is what causes the exception. Do you want to add 13 months (ie. 1/2013)? If simply wanting to pretend the number if a month then do that - without asking Python to try and treat it as a valid date.

Comment: And there might very well be a difference in strf[p]time parsing; however this has not to do with the format call which simply results in a string that is then used as an argument.